# spring-security-oauth2 custom error handling

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring security oauth2 and doing authentication via custom ClientDetailsService , from that ClientDetailsService i am throwing ClientRegistrationException and i want to get that execption message and return it in the response body .

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AuthServerConfig.class);

@Autowired
private MongoClientDetailsService mongoClient;

@Override
/**
 * Configures access for the "/oauth/token_key" endpoint which exposing the public key used
 *  for signing the tokens.
 *  The endpoint is secured by default (by Spring) with access rule "denyAll()"
 */
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}

@Override
/**
 * Configure Spring to use the custom ClientDetails (which linked with Mongo)
 * in order to authorize the clients requests
 */
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    logger.info(new LocalizedMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle(Consts.LOGGING_MSG),
            "mongo-authentication"));
    clients.withClientDetails(mongoClient);
}
}
```

and the client credentials service :

```
@service
public class MongoClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MongoClientDetailsService.class);

@Autowired
private IClientCredentialsRepository clientCredentialsRepo;

public MongoClientDetailsService() {
}

@Override
public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId)
        throws ClientRegistrationException {
    try {
        Optional<ClientCredentials> retVal = clientCredentialsRepo.findByClientId(clientId);
        if (!retVal.isPresent()) {
            logger.error(new LocalizedMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle(Consts.LOGGING_MSG),
                    "client-not-found-in-db", clientId));
            throw new InvalidGrantException("user is not present.");
        }
        return createClient();
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        logger.error(new LocalizedMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle(Consts.LOGGING_MSG),
                "exception-on-load-client", clientId, e.fillInStackTrace()));
        throw new ClientRegistrationException("Error on loading client");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Don't just say what you want, tell us what you have tried and what error you have got.

Comment: Hey , currently i am receiving the default error oauh2 : {
    "timestamp": 1597062914711,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/oauth/token"
}, i have tried several option , none of them seems to work , i want to override the oauth2 error handling , and to customize the response body and status, so i will be able to receive the exception thrown from the client details service and act accordingly and adjust the response body